# How do I display each number with corresponding value?

Tags: c#

I have an assignment where I need to calculate the amount of money for 2 people where we have 2 different interest rates. I need to display the amount of money that they would have at each of the given age. The issue is that it only prints the final amount which is 60 years old, how do I print the correct amount at the correct age? Here is the code

```
Console.WriteLine("*************************Investing vs.Savings ************************* \n");
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-25} {1,-30} {2,-30}","Age", "Linda's Account", "John's Account");
        Console.Write("-----------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        for(int age=20;age<=60;age+=10)
        {
            double Linda = 1000;
            double John = 1000;

            for (int year=1;year<=40;year++)
            {
                double retLin = 0.06;
                double retJon = 0.015;
                Linda += Linda * retLin;
                John += John * retJon;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-25}{1,-30:0.00} {2,-35:0.00}", age, Linda, John);
        }

        Console.Read();
```

Comment: How does `age` factor into your inner `for` loop, where you calculate the `Linda` and `John` variables?

Comment: So for my assignment the age starts at 20 years old and ends at 60. We want to see at each decade how much money do they have. The inner for loop is to add the interest rates for 40 years.

Comment: Yes, your code uses an inner `for` to calculate the total interest for 40 years. Where is the code that attempts to output how much money they have each decade? You only output the total after 40 years. If you want it to output every decade, then you need to add that to your inner `for` - check the value of `year` after each pass, and if `year` is evenly divisible by 10, output the amount at that point.

Comment: You do the same calculation regardless of what `age` is, so you always get the same result. The only place where you use `age` is printing the left-most column. How do you want to factor `age` into the math calculation?

Comment: Oh I see so the first for loop is only printing the left column of the age. I am trying to factor in the age and output the different amount of money at each decade. I am having issues trying to figure that out.

Comment: So if `age` is 20, what _should_ the final output for `Linda` and `John` be?

Comment: So at age 20 they both should be 1000, that is the starting money that they have. Then it increases with the interest rates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I figured it right, your desired response is a line of output for each person's balance on each deacde. To do this you only need one iteration in wich balances are increased based on each person's interest rate.

But to calculate the interest rate correctly, it should be added to the balance on every year. So a fixed inner loop of 10 iterations is needed for each decade.

The code is:

```
double Linda = 1000;
double John = 1000;
double retLin = 0.06;
double retJon = 0.015;

for (int age = 30; age <= 60; age += 10)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Linda += Linda * retLin;
        John += John * retJon;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("{0,-25}{1,-30:0.00} {2,-35:0.00}", age, Linda, John);
}
```

Note that this will not print tha balance on the starting decade (you can simply print the starting values before the loop operations).

Comment: Oh I see thank you so it iterates every 10 times, and my issue was that I iterated it 40 times. I misread my own code I thought the inner for loop is to state how many years thank for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need (comments in code):

```
Console.WriteLine("*************************Investing vs.Savings ************************* \n");
Console.WriteLine("{0,-25} {1,-30} {2,-30}", "Age", "Linda's Account", "John's Account");
Console.Write("-----------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

// It always is good idea to store info in variables, to give
// them meaning and easily parametrize the code.
var baseAge = 20;
var ageStep = 10;
var finalAge = 60;
// Of course, it would not make sense if you'd have just simple loop
// i = 0, i < limit, i++.
for (int age = baseAge; age <= finalAge; age += ageStep)
{
    double Linda = 1000;
    double John = 1000;
    // Here you missed starting point, as it always calculated 
    // as if we were in first loop - we need account for that.
    for (int year = age; year <= 40; year++)
    {
        double retLin = 0.06;
        double retJon = 0.015;
        Linda += Linda * retLin;
        John += John * retJon;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-25}{1,-30:0.00} {2,-35:0.00}", age, Linda, John);
}

Console.Read();
```

Comment: When I tried out the code the inner for loop is calculating the money at every decade incorrectly? It made the starting age at year 60